# Matlab regression returns beta coffecient not right?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to caclulate the beta coffecients with a regression using something like regstat. My Matlab code looks likes:

```
%get stock
sym = 'F'
%calculaltes returns with output of standard Open High Low Close
[o,h,l,clS]=YahooGetData(sym, priords, now,'d')
y = diff(clS)

%index like S&P 500
symIdx='^GSPC'
[o,h,l,clI]=YahooGetData(sym, priords, now,'d')
x = diff(clI)

mdl = regstats(x,y)
```

My beta coffeicients always return 1 and 0 no matter what stock symbol I use. Is there any reason why this is? What do you think I am doing anything wrong? I also get the same results using polyfit.

Thanks

Comment: If this is Matlab, then it's not R.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid big, I replaced with:

```
retIdx,o,h,l,clI]=YahooGetData(symIdx, priords, now,'d')
```

not use sym. DOH!. Sorry about that